# OSM API Satellite Imagery

Tags: python, api, openstreetmap, satellite-image

My goal is to find a way to download (with Python) satellite images given coordinates describing a rectangle. I've never really found a precise and free solution (no business here, just school stuff).

At first I tried Google Maps' API, which worked perfectly but turned out to be paying after a certain time. I then considered using OpenStreetMap, but again I had a lot of trouble finding information on how to obtain those.

Can you please help me with a simple solution?

Answer (score 4):

OpenStreetMap only provides map data. OpenStreetMap doesn't have aerial imagery and thus also no satellite imagery API.

If you are looking for free aerial imagery then take a look at [OpenAerialMap](https://openaerialmap.org/).